# How to close pop up window, when there is no XPath for close button?

Tags: selenium

When I clicked on a some link, the popup window is opened on new browser.
I want to close that pop up window, but I am unable to find out the locator. 
How to close window, when it is opened as popup in Selenium?

Comment: Can you consider showing us your work please?

Comment: You've not mentioned what language is you following and also not shared your effort (code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this this,it worked for me

```
    // Before new window
    String currentWindow=driver.getWindowHandle();
    //After window new open
    Set<String> handles=driver.getWindowHandles();
    //to make set having only one single/current window value
    handles.remove(currentWindow);
    String[] handlesArray = handles.toArray(new String[handles.size()]);

    driver.switchTo().window(handlesArray[0]).close();
```

Comment: After adding above code my child window gets closed but it gives an error as org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no such window: target window already closed.

Comment: after adding  driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow); error is gone.above codes are work fine for me

Comment: Yes , u need to switch back to current window. then only u can continue with remaining steps. else selenium command will try to act on previous window which u have closed, ultimately results in NoSuchWindowException